# How are methods invoked using Reflection

Tags: c#

I want to  know that how the methods are invoked using Reflection in c# .

Here is the code i have picked from book

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Reflection;
> class MyClass {
> int x;
> int y;
> public MyClass(int i, int j) {
> x = i;
> y = j;
> }
> public int Sum() {
> return x+y;
> }
> public bool IsBetween(int i) {
> if((x < i) && (i < y)) return true;
> else return false;
> }
> public void Set(int a, int b) {
> Console.Write("Inside Set(int, int). ");
> x = a;
>       y = b;
> Show();
> }
> // Overload set.
> public void Set(double a, double b) {
> Console.Write("Inside Set(double, double). ");
> x = (int) a;
> y = (int) b;
> Show();
> }
> public void Show() {
> Console.WriteLine("Values are x: {0}, y: {1}", x, y);
> }
> public void Show1() {
> Console.WriteLine("Hello");
> } 
> }
> class InvokeMethDemo {
> static void Main() {
> Type t = typeof(MyClass);
> MyClass reflectOb = new MyClass(10, 20);
> int val;
> Console.WriteLine("Invoking methods in " + t.Name);
> Console.WriteLine();
> MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
> // Invoke each method.
> foreach(MethodInfo m in mi) {
> // Get the parameters.
> ParameterInfo[] pi = m.GetParameters();
> if(m.Name.Equals("Set", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
> pi[0].ParameterType == typeof(int)) {
> object[] args = new object[2];
> args[0] = 9;
> args[1] = 18;
> m.Invoke(reflectOb, args);
> }
> else if(m.Name.Equals("Set", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
> pi[0].ParameterType == typeof(double)) {
> object[] args = new object[2];
> args[0] = 1.12;
> args[1] = 23.4;
> m.Invoke(reflectOb, args);
> }
> else if(m.Name.Equals("Sum", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
> val = (int) m.Invoke(reflectOb, null);
> Console.WriteLine("sum is " + val);
> }
> else if(m.Name.Equals("IsBetween", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
> object[] args = new object[1];
> args[0] = 14;
> if((bool) m.Invoke(reflectOb, args))
> Console.WriteLine("14 is between x and y");
> }
> else if(m.Name.Equals("Show", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
> m.Invoke(reflectOb, null);
>
> }
> else if(m.Name.Equals("Show1", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
> m.Invoke(reflectOb, null);
> }         
> }
> }
> }
> ```

1. Is the method invoked based on the number and type of parameters passed.If yes then Why

the Compiler does not show error as the **same statement is used to call method show and

show1**?

OR

1. The **method is invoked based on some reference value of m**(MethodInfo m) **and the 
   number of parameters.**

Comment: The method is invoked based only on the MethodInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the Methods using MethodBase Class.

Invokes the method or constructor represented by the current instance, using the specified parameters.
Refer this link [Method Invoking in Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)